# Basis of solution sets

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that the collection of all solutions to $\sum_{i=0}^nA_iy^{(i)}(t)=0$ form a vector space. But in which way can one find out its basis? Of course I already learned what the basis is. But the key question is, how to *prove* that it is?

Comment: If the $A_i$ are constants, then you look at the polynomial whose coefficients are the $A_i$; if it has distinct roots $a_1,\dots,a_n$, then the basis is given by the functions $e^{a_jt}$. If the roots aren't distinct, it's a little trickier, and if the $A_i$ aren't constants, fuggedaboudid.

Comment: how do you know they are the basis?

Comment: I can prove that they are linearly independent, and I can prove that for any set of initiaql condition there's a solution of this type, so they also span the solution space.

Comment: why is it that for any set of initial condition there's a solution of this type?

Comment: Write down the system of linear equations you'd have to solve to find the solution satisfying given initial conditions.

Comment: Any thoughts or questions about the answers so far?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at an example, $$y''+y'-2y=0$$ It seems that you know that $y_1(t)=e^t$ and $y_2(t)=e^{-2t}$ form a basis for the vector space of all solutions, but you want to know why.

First, let's prove that these two solutions are linearly independent. Suppose $$Ae^t+Be^{-2t}=0$$ identically (that is, for all $t$). Let $t=0$; you get $A+B=0$, so $B=-A$, so $$Ae^t-Ae^{-2t}=0$$ so $A=0$ or else $e^t-e^{-2t}$ is identically zero. The latter is nonsense ($e^t>1>e^{-2t}$ for $t>0$), so $A=0$, so $B=0$, so the two functions are linearly independent.

Given any solution $f$ of the differential equation, we can find $A,B$ such that if $g=f-Ae^t-Be^{-2t}$ then $g(0)=g'(0)=0$. But $g$ satisfies the differential equation, so $g$ is identically zero, so $f(t)=Ae^t+Be^{-2t}$.

Comment: "we can find A,B such that..", could you explain it a little bit please?

Comment: You take $g(t)=f(t)-Ae^t-Be^{-2t}$ and plug in $t=0$ to get one linear equation in the unknowns $A,B$; you differentiate, then plug in $t=0$ to get a second linear equation in $A,B$; you solve this system of 2 linear equations in 2 unknowns.

Comment: When you write down the equation, you automatically admit that there exists a linear combination of the two vectors, which and the derivatives of which coincide with those of f. But how do you know such linear combination exists?

Comment: If you can solve the system of 2 equations in 2 unknowns, then you have found the linear combination, thus proving that it exists. So I urge you to write out the 2 equations and to convince yourself that the system has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer to this is:

$\text{The Basis theorem}$ (from linear algebra):

Let $A$ be a $p$-dimensional subspace of $R^n$. Any linearly independent set of exactly $p$ elements in $A$ is automatically a basis for $A$. Also, any set of $p$ elements of $A$ that $span$ $A$ is a basis for $A$.

Note that a vector space (which in your case is given by the solutions of your system) is something completely different than the basis of a matrix. A vector space is just a mathematical structure formed by vectors, which can be added together and multiplied by numbers.